# Client to consume a WSO2 WSAS Web Service with Username Token Security

Tags: java, web-services, security, wso2

I need to implement a client to consume a Web Service that is deployed on the WSO2 WSAS with username token security.

I can use the stub generated by the wsdl2java, a dynamic approach is not necessary right now.

There is any tutorial that can help me to accomplish this task? I have already searched but without success!

Best regards,
Ukrania

Comment: You can always contact WSO2 guys in their dev channel. mailto:carbon-dev@wso2.org

Answer (score 3):

Follow-up guide http://wso2.org/library/demonstrations/deploying-java-web-service-wsas-securing-it-username-token-policy-0

Comment: This link only has info on how to secure it using UT, and I have provided a link below in my comment where there is a client Java code to invoke the UT secured service

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://wso2.org/library/articles/content-filtering-data-services-user-roles#Code_Generated_Java_Client) could be what you are looking for. It has code that uses the Rampart module to consume secure service.